# Bitcoin "stolen"

Tags: transactions, electrum

Im a bit of a noob when it comes too bitcoin but i still know some basics. I Ordered 0.00145603 bitcoin ($100AU) from Paybis and the crypto went into my account and then was taken out.
[image: Transaction History]

If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for your loss.

It looks like someone else has knowledge of the private key corresponding to your wallet. Most likely you downloaded malware instead of Electrum or you were tricked into using a wallet that someone else generated. Alternatively, there may be malware on your computer that extracts private keys. Either way, you should quarantine this wallet, investigate whether your computer or just the wallet is affected, and ensure that any future wallet setups are more secure.